# Deploying profiles from Production to Sandbox

Tags: deployment

I have been researching this and I still have some questions regarding this. Some of the responses have said that it is a dangerous thing to do because you could be granting greater permissions to profiles by doing this.

In my situation, I would be moving them from a Production environmnet which should only have more tight security than the sandbox I would be deploying to - so I wouldn't think I would have to worry about granting rights to anything greater than it already is in sandbox.

Another question I have is : If I am deploying a profile from Prod which already exists in both environments to a sandbox with objects not yet in Prod will the deployment take those into account and keep them in the profile during the deployment ? In other words, in the end I would have a complete profile.

If anybody has any other advice\warnings with this or would like to share their experiences I would be very grateful.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects ,Fields along with profiles form the complete metadata for many things like field level security,record types ,page layouts ,etc .Hence whenever you will move any field or object move along with profiles to avoid missing of field level security,record types and permissions on object.

So if you are moving any profile from prod to sandbox make sure you move objects ,fields ,record types along with that so as not to miss any permissions .

Now coming to second question that if the objects wont exists in prod and you do a deployment of profile only then i think it will override your permissions of object existing in sandbox and hence can be dangerous .

Comment: Thank you very much for your response Mohith.I think I understand the answer to the first question.The only question I have in it is that the record types need to already exist in the sandbox in order to change the rights in a deploy, correct.I've already heard record types needed to be manually added because of their original id. Is that correct ?If I understand you correctly in the 2nd question,I don't understand why\how Prod would be able to overrite the field settings of an object which only exists in Sandbox.That seems to go against the idea that you must specify a field during a deploy.

Comment: ok so record type dont need to be manually added .You can use changesets and deploy .also why an override will happen is because the metadata of profiles decide field level security and hence when you deploy profiles metadata is overrriden

Answer (score 0):

On the second question, regarding objects existing in sandbox that do not exist in production: I have just "tested" this, and it appears that the profiles from production will only overwrite on objects or settings that also exist in the sandbox. I just deployed 9 profiles from production to a sandbox environment with three new custom objects and hundreds of custom fields. At the field level and at the object level, the sandbox permissions are indeed intact.